# Showing that, for $c,d\in\Bbb N$, $c|d$ implies $c\leq d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility

I need help solving the following. My idea is to use Euclid's algorithm however I was told that I can simply prove this just with natural numbers.

> Prove that for all natural numbers $c$ and $d$, if $c|d$ then $c ≤ d.$

Comment: If $n\in\Bbb N$ then $n\ge1$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown therefore?

Comment: What does $c\mid d$ mean to you?

Comment: @Arthur c divides d

Comment: And what does that _mean_?

Comment: That for all natural numbers, c ≤ d? @Arthur

Comment: That's not the definition of the word "divides". What does the phrase "$c$ divides $d$" actually _mean_?

Comment: What Arthur is trying to get at, @k.rudin, is the actual definition of what it means for a number to divide another. What is the exact relation between them? There's an equation somewhat associated with this, depending on how it was introduced to you.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer thank you. I am using Brooks text, A Transition to Adv. Math. I'm a bit confused because Euclid's algorithm and the division algorithm imply two different ways to show what it means to divide.

Comment: What do the two of them say, then? Presumably, either can be used to get you from $c\mid d$ to $c\leq d$, so you're free to pick your favourite.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** *(broad overview)*

Recall what it means for a natural number to divide another - it means one is an integer multiple of the other. Since both are positive, that integer must also be positive (i.e. it is $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or ...).

Consider the ratio of the first two integers and see what you can conclude.

---

**Solution:**

If $c,d \in \Bbb N$ with $c|d$, then there exists $n \in \Bbb Z^+$ such that

> $$d = nc$$

Consider the ratio of $d$ and $c$:

> $$\frac d c = n$$

Since $n$ is a positive integer,

> $$\frac d c = n \geq 1 \implies \frac d c \geq 1 \implies d \geq c$$

concluding the proof.